# Running Tensorflow on GeForce 940M (Ubuntu)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm running the CIFAR-10 classification from the Tensorflow for the very first time on my laptop with GeForce 940M. I'm running the training with the pre-defined parameters as follows:

```
python cifar10_train.py
```

after step 1800 I'm getting the following errors:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_event.cc:33] Error polling for event status: failed to query event: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1182] failed to enqueue async memcpy from device to host: CUDA_ERROR_ILLEGAL_ADDRESS; host dst: 0x7ff8e9bf26c0; GPU src: 0x5011c0600; size: 16=0x10
F tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_event_mgr.cc:105] Unexpected Event status: 1
I tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:3304] stream 0x35e7190 did not block host until done; was already in an error state
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Does anybody have any idea?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help! Any advice is kindly appreciated!

Comment: That's actually two questions. You should take the second one off this question and ask a new question.

Comment: If you successfully ran for 1800 steps, it must be mostly working.  It's odd that the error you cite would be the first problem.  Is there anything else in the logs?  Is it possible you exhausted the memory, or there's interference with the display driver using the same GPU?